# Why does EF send request twice for each query to SQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I used EF code first, and I have a query like this:

```
var test = _units.ToList(); // _units is >> _units = _uow.Set<Unit>();
```

When I profile query with SQL Server Profiler, I have the same query twice - like this :

[image]

What's problem ? Create and edit work fine and I just have one request.

Comment: It does not. First entry is "Batch Starting", second is "Batch Completed". These are complementary.

Comment: @AntonGogolev thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not reading the profiler output correctly.

- `BatchStarting` indicates that the query is **beginning**.
- `BatchCompleted`
  indicates that the query is **complete**.

The query is not actually executing twice.